# Is it too late to start outdoor aquaponics?

Tags: aquaponic

Is it too late to add edible fish for an aquaponics project in zone 7A?  It looks like I may be too late for fingerling tilapia.

Comment: Not sure this topic is covered by this site. See the help center for details on what topics we cover.